# no tests were run on an ember test

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs, ember-cli, ember-testing

When I run an `ember test` it says

```
1..0
# tests 0
# pass  0
# fail  0

# ok
No tests were run, please check whether any errors occurred in the page (ember test --server) and ensure that you have a test launcher (e.g. PhantomJS) enabled.
```

There are also zero tests run when I do an `ember test --server`. However, when I navigate to http://localhost:4200/tests, all the tests run. How can I get the tests to run with ember-cli?
I'm using
`"ember": "2.3.1"`
`"ember-cli": "1.13.8"`
`"phantomjs": "^1.9.18"` which resolves to `"1.9.20"`
Let me know if there are any other dependency versions I should list.

Comment: what is test_page in testem.json ?

Comment: Didn't even know I needed a testem.json file =/ Just created one though with `"test_page": "tests/index.html?hidepassed"` Now the tests run with `just ember test --server` but not with `just ember test`. When I run the latter it does nothing after building, it just hangs.

Comment: can you share repo?

Comment: I can't, it's a project for work.

Comment: what if use such testem.json https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector/blob/master/testem.json ?

Comment: Yeah that's the exact testem.json that I'm using. I don't know if this helps but when I kill the proccess the stacktrace shows `pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 455, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)`

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Make sure you have a `testem` config file.

I recently ran in to this issue myself after upgrading from an older version of `ember-cli` to a newer version. It wasn't the upgrade the caused the issue, but my own simple mistake.

During the upgrade, `testem.json` was renamed to `testem.js`. I changed the file name but forgot to update it in `git`, so I effectively lost my `testem` config.

Without any config, `testem` will just fall back to its default behavior. This means it won't use the test harness from your ember app, but it will instead have its default test harness (a Jasmine one) that runs no tests.

You should ensure that you have a `testem.json` or `testem.js` in the root directory of your project. [This is an example](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output/blob/bba3310e3f573594076634698e84d6de74659e6e/testem.js):

```
/*jshint node:true*/
module.exports = {
  "framework": "qunit",
  "test_page": "tests/index.html?hidepassed",
  "disable_watching": true,
  "launch_in_ci": [
    "PhantomJS"
  ],
  "launch_in_dev": [
    "PhantomJS",
    "Chrome"
  ]
};
```